# Discord.js fetchMessage reactions.get cannot get users

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I tried to use `fetchMessage()` in a channel. I successfully found the message I want and I tried to get the reaction  of the message using `message.reactions.get("")`

These are part of my code:

```
var msg = await channel.fetchMessage(the-message-id);
var reaction = msg.reactions.get("")

for (const user of reaction.users.values()) {
                  const data = user.id;
                  reacted.push(data);
                }
```

Then I want to push the data of user into the array `reacted`.

I try to get the `users` object from `reactions.get()` but it's empty. I'm sure that me and my bot have reacted  on the message and the `reactions.get().count` also shows both of us reacted (cuz it shows 2). Now I really don't know what to do to get the `users` object from it ;-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `reaction.fetchUsers()`, and then you will have access to `reaction.users`. You don't have to use this if the reactions were added after the bot starts.

```js
var msg = await channel.fetchMessage(the-message-id);
var reaction = msg.reactions.get("")
reaction.fetchUsers();

for (const user of reaction.users.values()) {
    const data = user.id;
    reacted.push(data);
}
```